# Need help conditionally vectorizing a list

Tags: python

I need help vectorizing the code below in python. The current loop is way too slow for my needs.

If a is your list

[-1.5,-1,-1,0,0,-1,0,1.5,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1.5,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1.5...]

And the desired output we obtain after the current code below: 
[-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1...]

```
for index, item in enumerate(a): 
    if item == 1.5:
       a[index] = 1
    elif item == -1.5:
       a[index] = -1
    elif a[index] == 0:
       a[index] = 0
    elif (a[index] == 1 or a[index] == -1) and a[index-1] ==0:
       a[index] = 0
    else:
       a[index] = a[index-1]
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's not how SO works :-) Show us your attempts at "vectorizing" (Numpy?) this code and where you are stuck, then we can work from there....

Comment: so I am trying to figure out the part where I compare a[index] to a[index - 1]. I am not sure how to vectorize this part. I created a secondary list that is a different value every time 1.5 or -1.5 occurs, and then I am trying to do a conditional ffill() upon that group to the first list.

Comment: You can't "vectorize a list", you vectorize operations on the list. I'm not sure I understand the question properly but you might want `np.roll()` to shift the index by 1

Comment: yes a little typo exuse me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [-1.5,-1,-1,0,0,-1,0,1.5,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1.5,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1.5]
s  = pd.Series(l)
cond1 = (s == 1.5)
cond2 = (s == -1.5)
cond3 = (s == 0)
cond4 = ((s == 1) | (s ==  -1)) & (s.shift() == 0)
out = pd.Series(pd.np.select([cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4],[1, -1, 0 ,0], pd.np.nan)).ffill()
out.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[-1.0,
 -1.0,
 -1.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 1.0,
 1.0,
 1.0,
 1.0,
 1.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 1.0,
 1.0,
 1.0,
 1.0,
 1.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 -1.0]
```

Note: This is a vectorized way of doing if then else using Numpy method np.select, which is accessed via the pandas import using pd.np.select.   The default value will be np.nan which allows the forward fill to get previous rows value in that default case.

Comment: I believe this is right, but when I apply it to my larger list it doesn't work, but I think I have it from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @Bart suggested, you can vectorize at least the first three operations pretty easily using numpy. The last condition is a bit trickier, since you need to know where the first three cases failed. You also need to be careful, since if you do your calculations in-place, your early changes might affect your later conditions (that is, you assign some values to 1, then later check for values that equal 1). All told, you could do something like the following:

```
a = np.array(a)
cond1 = a == 1.5
cond2 = a == -1.5
cond3 = ((a == 1) | (a == -1))[1:] & (a[:-1] == 0)
cond4 = ~(cond1[1:] | cond2[1:] | cond3)
a[cond1] = 1
a[cond2] = -1
a[1:][cond3] = 0
a[1:][cond4] = a[1:][cond4]
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help; however, I do not really understand what a[index] would be

Comment: @BrendanNewell Sorry, didn't actually test the code, was just trying to give you an idea of how to approach the problem. I've edited the answer, and the code should work now. But really, as others have said, SO is not a code writing service. You need to be trying things yourself and asking about issues and errors, not asking someone else to solve your problem for you.